# Thread dump analysis when live server has high CPU usage

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, production-environment, thread-dump

From the perspective of a typical MVC/web application developed in Java using some database: Let's say the app server is hosted on one server and the database is hosted on another server. If we get high CPU usage/slowness on live on server (hosting app server) then we take threads dumps & figure out the "culprit" thread based on below rules:

1) If there are slow running SQLs (fired from within the web application)/database is slow then it will never result in server hosting app server to have high CPU usage. Database slowness will only make application slow. Database slowness causes application THREADs to be in BLOCKED/WAITING state as those threads "fight/compete" to get "limited" database access (typical connection pooling stuff).

2) The culprit will always be threads (in RUNNABLE state) doing some activity on app server layer like running in a pretty long while loop and/or doing some intensive operation/calculation.

Can any one please help validate above understanding?

Comment: Correct, `BLOCKED`, `WAITING` or `TIMED_WAITING` do not consume CPU so you should look at those that are `RUNNABLE`.

Comment: @JohnVint My question was not around possible "thread states" that cause high CPU (on server hosting app server). It was around app versus DB - who killed the CPU?

Comment: If the DB is on another server (which I would expect it to) then the processing being done on the DB will NOT effect your CPU. The request will be on a `socketRead` which is blocked waiting. In other words, the DB working will not cause your CPU to increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that if the DB is a bottleneck, then the app server will not generally have high CPU utilization.

It is true that having many app server threads in a RUNNABLE state can result in high CPU utilization, but it is not **ALWAYS** the cause of high CPU utilization.

The other main alternative occurs when the app server JVM is running low on memory (and/or the app is generating enormous amounts of garbage) and the JVM is spending an inordinate amount of effort (CPU) on garbage collection.

There are numerous tools, such as jvisualvm (included with JDK) that will make it immediately obvious where the problem lies.

Comment: I stumbled upon a related article today which supports your view: https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshoot-sudden-cpu-spikes?edition=155252&utm_source=Weekly%20Digest&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=wd%202016-06-22